# How can I install Gym even. on Anaconda(Mac OS)

Tags: python, anaconda, openai-gym

When I try to install Gym I take "ERROR: File "setup.py" not found. Directory cannot be installed in editable mode" error

I wrote these codes and they doesn't exits.

```
pip install gym
pip install -e '.[all]'
```

[image: After I wrote codes]

Plese someone help me? Thanks for all.

Comment: I don't know when I search how to install gym it says that
https://pypi.org/project/gym/0.7.4/#installation

Comment: But i cant see gym libary on my anaconda navigators envs? What should i do?